# Figure not updating using matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, raspberry-pi3, tkinter-canvas

I've hit a wall and I haven't been able to find any forum posts about the same issue online (at least in my few hours of searching).

To preface; I have little knowledge of Python except what I have learnt over the past 2 months (slowly) coding this in my spare time. My apologies if I'm not making sense, I don't quite understand the syntax of the Python commands yet. It should also be noted this is being coded on a Raspberry Pi Model 3 B+.

I have done some brief troubleshooting rearranging the placement of the animate function and the figure itself inside and outside of the app class and the Melting Point/Manual Method class but I can't seem to get it to animate. At most I have been able to display only the figure alone with no animation. It should be noted the same lines of code work in a previous iteration of the application, but since rearranging with classes the figure no longer updates.

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
import time
from time import sleep
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import csv
import tkinter
import numpy as np

class SampleApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.fullscreen = True
        self.switch_frame(MeltPoint)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.fullscreen = True
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.fst = Button(self, text="Toggle Fullscreen", command=self.fullscreen_toggle)
        self.fst.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky='NW')

    def fullscreen_toggle(self):
        if self.fullscreen == False:
            self.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", True)
            self.fullscreen = True
        else:
            self.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", False)
            self.fullscreen = False

###########################################################

def animate(i):
    pullData = open("/home/pi/cpu_temp.txt","r").read()
    dataList = pullData.split('\n')
    xList = []
    yList = []
    for eachLine in dataList:
        if len(eachLine) > 1:
            x,y = eachLine.split(',')
            xList.append(float(x))
            yList.append(float(y))

    a.clear()
    a.plot(xList, yList)
    a.set_xlabel("Time[MM.SS]")
    a.set_ylabel("Temperature[°C]")

class Graph(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)            
        f = Figure(figsize=(9, 5), dpi=60)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=100)

###########################################################


class MeltPoint(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        title = Label(self, text="Melting Point Determination").grid(row=0, column=1)       
        b1 = Button(self, height=4, width=12, text='Add Method', command=lambda: master.switch_frame(AddMethod)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='')
        b2 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Manual Method', command=lambda: master.switch_frame(ManMeth)).grid(row=2,column=0, sticky='')
        b3 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Recent Analysis/Results').grid(row=3,column=0, sticky='')
        b4 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Setup').grid(row=4,column=0, sticky='')
        b5 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Exit').grid(row=5,column=0, sticky='')
        tl = Frame(self, height=180, width=350, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=1, rowspan=3, column=1, sticky='')
###########################################################
        graph = Graph(self).grid(row=4, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky='')
###########################################################


class ManMeth(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        title = Label(self, text="Manual Method").grid(row=0, column=1)
        b1 = Button(self, height=4, width=12, text='Home', command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MeltPoint)).grid(row=1, column=0)
        b2 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Method Settings', command=lambda: master.switch_frame(AddMethod)).grid(row=2, rowspan=2, column=0)
        b3 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Start Analysis').grid(row=4,column=0)
        b4 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Data Handling').grid(row=5,column=0)
        b5 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Save Method').grid(row=6,column=0)    
        vidfrm = Frame(self, height=180, width=350, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=4)
###########################################################
        graph = Graph(self).grid(row=5, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky='')
###########################################################


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

I expect the graph to update from a .txt file and readout CPU temp and time to plot on x and y axis, currently only a static figure displays. The graph should also update on both pages (manual method and melting point).

Answer (score 0):

To update, I have managed to get the graph to take the live information and update, however the graph stops updating when you leave the first page (and does not resume). To get to this stage I added the call to animate function to the SampleApp() mainloop, I removed the figure from it's class and plotted it independently (globally?, not sure on the terminology here), and lastly I added the call to canvas.get_tk_widget() to each frame class ("window/Page") being MeltPoint and ManMeth.

Again I'm sorry if i've butchered the python terminology i'm still learning and i've don't my best to describe my changes!

If anyone could help me with getting this graph updated on both pages I would be ever so grateful! :)

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
import time
from time import sleep
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import csv
import tkinter
import numpy as np

class SampleApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.fullscreen = True
        self.switch_frame(MeltPoint)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.fullscreen = True
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.fst = Button(self, text="Toggle Fullscreen", command=self.fullscreen_toggle)
        self.fst.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky='NW')

    def fullscreen_toggle(self):
        if self.fullscreen == False:
            self.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", True)
            self.fullscreen = True
        else:
            self.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", False)
            self.fullscreen = False

###########################################################

def animate(i):
    pullData = open("/home/pi/cpu_temp.txt","r").read()
    dataList = pullData.split('\n')
    xList = []
    yList = []
    for eachLine in dataList:
        if len(eachLine) > 1:
            x,y = eachLine.split(',')
            xList.append(float(x))
            yList.append(float(y))

    a.clear()
    a.plot(xList, yList)
    a.set_xlabel("Time[MM.SS]")
    a.set_ylabel("Temperature[°C]")



f = Figure(figsize=(9, 5), dpi=60)
a = f.add_subplot(111)

###########################################################


class MeltPoint(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        title = Label(self, text="Melting Point Determination").grid(row=0, column=1)       
        b1 = Button(self, height=4, width=12, text='Add Method', command=lambda: master.switch_frame(AddMethod)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='')
        b2 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Manual Method', command=lambda: master.switch_frame(ManMeth)).grid(row=2,column=0, sticky='')
        b3 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Recent Analysis/Results').grid(row=3,column=0, sticky='')
        b4 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Setup').grid(row=4,column=0, sticky='')
        b5 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Exit').grid(row=5,column=0, sticky='')
        tl = Frame(self, height=180, width=350, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=1, rowspan=3, column=1, sticky='')

###########################################################
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=4, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky='')
###########################################################


class ManMeth(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        title = Label(self, text="Manual Method").grid(row=0, column=1)
        b1 = Button(self, height=4, width=12, text='Home', command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MeltPoint)).grid(row=1, column=0)
        b2 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Method Settings', command=lambda: master.switch_frame(AddMethod)).grid(row=2, rowspan=2, column=0)
        b3 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Start Analysis').grid(row=4,column=0)
        b4 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Data Handling').grid(row=5,column=0)
        b5 = Button(self, height=4, width=12,  text='Save Method').grid(row=6,column=0)    
        vidfrm = Frame(self, height=180, width=350, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=4)
###########################################################
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=5, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky='')
###########################################################



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=100)
    app.mainloop()
```